# How to find which android application is loading a website using webview

Tags: php, android, webview

Is there any possibility to find out which android application (name of the app, developer etc) is loading a 3rd party website using webview?

Comment: this isn't possible (assuming site OR app is 3rd party)

Comment: Unless the software introduces itself in some way then no. You would need to have some kind of authentication process.

Comment: @snachmsm if the website is owned by someone I know but he doesn't know who's loading his site without his permission, isn't there any code (javascript / php) that we can add on the site and get the app detail?

Comment: I've posted reply as answer, check out

Answer (score 0):

app has to add some custom data for recognizing on server-side who sent this request, e.g. by adding some custom header. if app doesn't do that then server side gets only request from some IP and eventually can analyze screen size and some web engine and system properties (e.g. from user-agent, determining that Android is loading site). but still there is no way for getting info which particual app is loading given URL if this app won't introduce itself. `WebView` by default uses default headers (including user agent) and doesn't add anything extra e.g. like apps package